# royal slider does not work when jquery masonry loaded

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-masonry

I am really beginner at jquery - only general understanding + background in other programming languages.

I have royal slider wordpress plugin which works fine, until I load jquery masonry, with these settings:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var container = document.querySelector('#portfolio-masonry');
    var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
        gutter: 30,
        itemSelector: '.portfolio-block',
        columnWidth: container.querySelector('.grid-sizer')
    });

});
```

This somehow affects royalslider (no images are shown) with console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
```

It seems like some kind of conflict with querySelector. How can I fix this.

Website: WordPress (3.9 has masonry) & [royalslider](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/)

*Thanks in advance.*

**EDIT:**

1) I enqueue my masonry & settings in functions.php (wordpress)

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'redefined-reality-masonry', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/masonry-settings.js', array('masonry'), '20140401', true );
```

2) I use very simple html markup:

```
<div id="portfolio-masonry">
  <div class="portfolio-block"></div>
  <div class="portfolio-block"></div>
  ...
</div>
```

3) I use querySelector to direct masonry that i want to use specific width of column (and direct it to separate class ".grid-sizer". I did this so i could control *columnWidth* with use of  media queries for responsive purposes, since directly I cannot input that in js (only integer px, not even percentage! so its important in my design).

4) Masonry works perfect, it is only used in few archive and custom pages of template. But the RoyalSlider plugin, the slider stops working. The pages containing slider do not have masonry, however I figure that in case in future i decide to have one with both... well i need a solution for this.

I dont know what else should i add :D

Comment: Do you have an HTML element in your page with `id="portfolio-masonry"` and `class="grid-sizer"`?

Comment: Only in one page where masonry is in action. Other pages do not have these classes and still prompt this error.

Comment: You'll have to post more code to show exactly how you're implementing this. If you're getting this error on all pages, then you're calling masonry on all pages. The `Uncaught TypeError` is fatal, and will stop jQuery execution.

Comment: Hi, I posted more. Also noticed, error only appears when the page contains slider - others are fine.

Comment: within '#portfolio-masonry' is there a element with the class '.grid-sizer'?

Comment: no, and if i do add it, everything breaks :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem. The issue here was that masonry was loaded in all of the pages (i enqueued it in the head). *Nothing to do with royalslider*!

However, the `querySelector` was looking for a an element with `.grid-sizer` in the pages where it did not have and masonry could not handle empty variable giving us: `Uncaught TypeError`.

1. So there are couple of option what we could have done here, just **remove masonry** js from the **rest of the pages** where it is not used.
2. Use **if statement** to check if variable is **not empty**
3. Or use something instead of `querySelectro`. (what i did, you can see bellow)

JS (right, i also decided to use isotope, but that does not change the fact that it uses masonry)

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(function () {
            var $alpha = $('#portfolio-masonry');
            var $container = $('#isotope-variables');

            $container.isotope({
                itemSelector: '.portfolio-block',
                masonry: {
                    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
                    gutter: '.gutter-sizer'
                }
            }).isotope('insert', $alpha.find('.portfolio-block'));
        });
    });
```

Markup

```
<div id="portfolio-masonry">
    <div class="portfolio-block"></div>
    <div class="portfolio-block"></div>
    ...
</div>
<div id="isotope-variables">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
</div>
```

Works like a charm. Responsive with custom css for column and gutter width + clean code